# How can i use kotlinOptions in Java Application in AndroidStudioProject?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm

I do not understand what KotlinOptions is.
I am using Kohii Library and this library tell me to add this KotlinOptions code in gradle file?
But I am using Java as main language for my android studio project How can i config this code below?

```kotlin
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
  jvmTarget = "1.8"
  freeCompilerArgs += [
      '-Xjvm-default=enable'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Kohii uses Kotlin with **JAVA8** features and you need to specify version of Java for Kotlin use in build.gradle. Even though your project is using Java as its primary language, the library you chose uses Kotlin. The good news is that Java and Kotlin are interoperable, the compiler just needs to be told how the Kotlin parts should be compiled.

**kotlinOptions** tells compiler different configurations for Kotlin. E.g:

**jvmTarget = "1.8"** (Java 8) - target version of the generated JVM bytecode (1.6, 1.8, 9, 10, 11 or 12), default is 1.6

**freeCompilerArgs** - A list of additional compiler arguments

**All configuration parametrs and explanations can be** [found here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#attributes-specific-for-jvm)

Put the configuration in build.gradle like this

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {...}
    kotlinOptions {...}
    ...

}
```

**[Probably you also need to enable Kotlin support to your project](https://medium.com/mindorks/enabling-kotlin-support-for-a-current-only-java-android-project-98c75e04384a)**

Comment: but my main language for android project is java

Comment: No problem, you can use Java as main Language. The library(Kohii) is written in Kotlin and that's why you need the configuration

Comment: Could not find method kotlinOptions() for arguments [build_7yfzq7ax8ab8r5xtglswvawpb$_run_closure1$_closure5@37ad7e] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: See updated answer. You need to enable Kotlin support for project

Comment: no sir it was giving me some error at sync , so i just quit the library for my project

Comment: KotlinOption is not available in android block in android project